# turn off noise on kinesis keyboard caps-lock

Tags: keyboard, kinesis-advantage

Does anyone know the key combo for turning off the beep that the Kinesis Contoured ergonomic keyboard makes when you hit Caps Lock?

I know this isn't totally programmer-specific, but everyone I know who has used a Kinesis keyboard is a coder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figured it out by reading [the manual](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/support/manuals.htm). You hit the "Program" and "hyphen" keys at the same time (no need to hold them down). Mine didn't give feedback to acknowledge the action, but now the beep doesn't occur when I hit Caps Lock.

Comment: To turn off the soft click for all key-presses, it's `Program Backslash`.

Comment: Blessed silence.

Comment: You're the real MVP Dan

Answer (score 29):

For the Advantage 2: Program + Shift + F8.
https://www.kinesis-ergo.com/support/technical-support/faqs-advantage2-keyboard/

Comment: Program + F8 did it for me.

Comment: Program + F8 disables the clicks (all keystrokes)
Program + Shift + F8 disables the beep (caps lock)